# How to install Linux subsystem for Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dism

I'm encountering a problem while trying to install Linux subsystem on my Windows 10 machine.

I'm following the procedure, found on [this URL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). I've tried to launch the following command (in Powershell, as an administrator), but I get an error message:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.1127


Error: 0x800f080c

Feature name VirtualMachinePlatform is unknown.
A Windows feature name was not recognized.
Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I've tried to use the `Get-Feature` option, but I don't know how to get this to work:

```
dism.exe /online /GET-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform
...
Error: 87

The get-feature option is unknown.
```

My DISM logfile looks as follows (only the first error lines):

```
2020-12-17 15:44:08, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9820 TID=9400 Failed to get the Update through CBS. - CDISMPackage::Internal_OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2020-12-17 15:44:08, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9820 TID=9400 Failed to get the underlying CBS Feature - CDISMPackage::OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2020-12-17 15:44:08, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9820 Feature name VirtualMachinePlatform is unknown. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetFeaturesFromCommandLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2020-12-17 15:44:08, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9820 TID=9400 Unknown features were specified on the command-line. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_GetFeaturesFromCommandLine(hr:0x800f080c)
2020-12-17 15:44:08, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9820 TID=9400 Failed to get the Feature List from the command line. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x800f080c)
2020-12-17 15:44:08, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=9820 TID=9400 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x800f080c)
```

Does anybody know how to proceed now?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `dism` command works perfectly for me.  Sure your OS meets minimum version requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is caused by the simpliest computer problem: never think that, because you start working with a computer, that you're dealing with the latest version, as you can see in following command response:

As mentioned in the referred URL:

> Requirements
>
> > For x64 systems: Version 1903 or higher, with Build 18362 or higher.

Commandline `winver` result:

```
Version 1709 (build ... 16229)
```

So, as mentioned by [fpmurphy](https://superuser.com/users/10157/fpmurphy) I'm dealing with a version of Windows, which is not able to handle this feature.

Comment: I hadn't thought to look at the dism build version. For information on 20H2 (build 19042.685) `dism` shows up with `Version: 10.0.19041.572`